# Python script Waiting for Parent to pass variable

Tags: python, import, parameter-passing

The script main.py calls variables from multiple different other scripts, through importing them I need to pass those variables to a script I am executing. But on import, the script gives an error:

```
NameError: name 'variable1' is not defined
```

I need to import that script and execute it later in the main.py. Here is the main.py:

```
from variablestorage.credentials import *
import scriptfolder.script


scriptfolder.script.function1(variable1, variable2, variable3)
```

I don't have these variables defined in the script.py because the main.py needs to pass them and if I define them the script.py doesn't use the variables passed from main.py. These are just scripts in different folders, not modules. I also dont import main.py in script.py because I want main.py to pass the variables to script.py. Here is the function I want to execute in script.py:

```
def function1(variable1, variable2, variable3):
 #some function
```

How do I import script.py into main.py without errors and then pass the variables when the function1 is executed?

Edit:
credentials.py where the main.py pulls variables from.

```
variable1 ='value'
variable2 ='value'
variable3 ='value'
```

Comment: Just a clarification, are the variables initiated later in the variablestorage? Could you share a bit more on how this looks?

Comment: Yes it is they are just defined there as variable1 = 'value'

Comment: Weird, what you did should work. It works on my machine (Python 3.10). Do you have your `PYTHONPATH` configured correctly? How do you run `main.py`?

Comment: I didn't configure python path. I run everything through VS Code. What do I need to configure so it works?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I referenced the variables outside the function that was being called. So when the variables in script.py where being set on import, the variables from main.py where not passed on.